# Attach DB doesn't work in SQL Server with Access denied error

Tags: sql-server

I am running into a peculiar issue.

I have an application where it detaches the DB and copies the files to a different folder as an export and should attach the DB as part of import automatically.

For testing I have provided the target and source servers same.

When I import I am getting Access denied exception for attaching. Even though it is on the same server. The user I am using is a sql server login not windows login.

After some looking I found that there are no explicit permissions for the sql server service acct user. So I have provided and it worked.

But surprising thing is, before giving explicit permissions when I create new DB it is creating, but saying access denied to attach.

How is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like the account running the SQL Server service doesn't have access to the folder you've moved the files to. Can you verify?

Comment: Yes I re-checked and provided explicit permissions and it worked